# Is there a way to see overall status of iCloud Drive in macOS?

Tags: icloud, macos

I have moved a large folder with many subfolders to my iCloud drive. If I dig around I can catch a status bar next to a file name (same as during a download), but it seems to be taking a lot longer to upload than I would think. Besides catching an upload in progress I don't see a way to tell what has been uploaded or is waiting. Is there anything I am missing?

Dropbox had a nifty menu bar icon that would display progress and pending files.

Answer (score 1):

### Yosemite

You can watch individual files in Finder, but there's no GUI for the progress of iCloud changes.

### El Capitan

In El Capitan and later a progress bar can be accessed by clicking on the wheel in the Finder sidebar.

> [image]

https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/all-the-little-things-osx-el-capitan-hidden-features/#icloud-drive-upload-progress-indicator (my blog)